# Intersection of 2 surface plots in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, intersections

My question is pretty much a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52953/intersection-of-two-surfaces). I'd like pgfplots to display the intersection between tho surface plots properly. Unfortunately, my function is quite different from the one in the mentioned question, so I don't know, where the surfaces will meet. Would there be any kind of workaround for this kind of function?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0.01:30]
\addplot3[surf] {0};
\addplot3[surf] {(1-0.3)*e^(-x*(y/100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-x*(y/100))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is a job for PSTricks...

Comment: As Jake already said, this is beyond the capabilities of pgfplots. The golatex forum has a related post in which the OP managed to generate the graphics as such with matlab and imported it via `\addplot3 graphics`: http://www.golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=9585&sid=3728d4cbae7136a9cdb3c08a0545968d (in german only - but pictures speak in their own language, I guess)

Comment: I just discovered this website http://www.tlhiv.org/mpgraph/ that render 3D surfaces in MetaPost (and other formats, such as PDF), with surface intersections. Unfortunately there is no TikZ output.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another *hackish* solution:

[image: withlines]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0.01:30]
\addplot3[surf] {min(0.,(1-0.3)*e^(-x*(y/100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-x*(y/100))};
\addplot3[surf] {max(0.,(1-0.3)*e^(-x*(y/100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-x*(y/100)))};
\addplot3[domain=4:30,samples=80,samples y=0,mark=none,black, opacity=0.5,thick]({x},{118.89/x},{0.});
\addplot3[domain=0:30,samples=80,samples y=0,mark=none,black, opacity=0.5,thick]({x},{30.},{max(0.,(1-0.3)*e^(-x*(30./100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-x*(30./100)))});
\addplot3[domain=0:30,samples=80,samples y=0,mark=none,black, opacity=0.5,thick]({x},{0.},{max(0.,(1-0.3)*e^(-x*(0./100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-x*(0./100)))});
\addplot3[domain=0:30,samples=80,samples y=0,mark=none,black, opacity=0.5,thick]({x},{0.},{min(0.,(1-0.3)*e^(-x*(0./100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-x*(0./100)))});
\addplot3[domain=0:30,samples=80,samples y=0,mark=none,black, opacity=0.5,thick]({0.},{x},{max(0.,(1-0.3)*e^(-0.*(x/100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-0.*(x/100)))});
\addplot3[domain=0:30,samples=80,samples y=0,mark=none,black, opacity=0.5,thick]({30.},{x},{max(0.,(1-0.3)*e^(-30.*(x/100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-30.*(x/100)))});
\addplot3[domain=0:30,samples=80,samples y=0,mark=none,black, opacity=0.5,thick]({30.},{x},{min(0.,(1-0.3)*e^(-30.*(x/100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-30.*(x/100)))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that this kind of solution is less flexible, because the correct hidden surface removal depends on the position of the camera, and also on special properties of shape of the functions. If one could know the point of view internally, one could generalize the `max` and `min` function to make it camera dependent and in this way simulate hidden surfaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both your solutions. Would you be so kind as to explain the rationale behind the value 118.89 and especially behind the second solution?  I won't need different camera angles, but I will need to plot a lot of similar functions.

Comment: Second solution meaning this one, the order changed because of my accepting this answer.

Comment: I got the solution by myself. I just was missing the rule: ln(e^{f(x)}) = f(x). Using that, I now understand where the 118.89 come from. Thanks again.

Comment: Missing a parentheses `)` at the end of the first `\addplot3`

Comment: I have found another hack that allows to plot an arbitrary number of surfaces correctly, without doing anything manually: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394066/38641. Moreover, it does not depend on the viewpoint.

Comment: @iavr. Very cool, can you test your code to solve this case. It would be nice to compare the final results.

Comment: @alfC I added a new answer. It looks like this is really beyond the capabilities of pgfplots.

Answer (score 19):

A combination of surface colors, opacities and parametric plots can get you close to the desired result:

[image: intersection_picture]

Code follows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0.01:30]
\addplot3[surf, opacity=0.25, blue, shader=flat] {0};
\addplot3[surf, opacity=0.25] {(1-0.3)*e^(-x*(y/100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-x*(y/100))};
\addplot3+[domain=4:30,samples=80,samples y=0,mark=none,black, opacity=0.5,thick]({x},{118.89/x},{0.});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this works? I am trying to modify it for the x=z plane and a different function in place of the exponential but failing. In fact as soon as I replace `{0}` with `{x}` in the first `addplot3` I just get two planes.

Comment: @Arrow what do you expect? You have a problem of scale. The surface looks a plane because of the scale.

Answer (score 9):

This question has already tons of excellent answers, but as far as I can see none of them exploits that `(1-0.3)*e^(-x*(y/100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-x*(y/100))=0` implies that `y=-1000*ln(0.7)/(3*x)=:pft/x` (`pft` is marmot language and means something like "convenient constant", but is hard to translate precisely;-), and that, in order to draw a plane, one really does not need to use `\addplot3`. All I am doing here is to draw the part `x*y>pft` first, than the curved surface, and then the `x*y<pft` part of the plane.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0.01:30,xlabel=$x$]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pft}{-1000*ln(0.7)/3}
\fill[blue] plot[variable=\x,domain={\pft/30}:30] ({\x},{\pft/\x},0) -- 
(30,30,0) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf] {(1-0.3)*e^(-x*(y/100)*(1-0.3))-e^(-x*(y/100))};
\fill[blue] plot[variable=\x,domain={\pft/30}:30] ({\x},{\pft/\x},0) -- 
(30,0,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,30,0) -- cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I am exploiting when I plot the curve: `118.89/x` in the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

Use `asymptote`, this is a more appropriate tool for plotting in 3D. 
With some additional work you can make it look like a `pgfplots` graph.
Below there are three ways of doing this with `asymptote`.

## Transparent surfaces

[image: two_surfaces]

```
settings.outformat="png";
settings.render=16;

import graph3;
import palette;

size3(150,IgnoreAspect);

currentprojection=orthographic(50,-60,0.4);
currentlight=(5,-3,1);

real f(pair z){return (1.-0.3)*exp(-z.x*(z.y/100.)*(1.-0.3))-exp(-z.x*(z.y/100.));}
real cero(pair z){return 0.;}

limits((0,0,-0.3),(30,30,0.1));
xaxis3(Label("$x$",1),blue,arrow=Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$y$",1),blue,arrow=Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$z$",1),blue,arrow=Arrow3);

surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(30,30),30,30,Spline);
surface s2=surface(cero,(0,0),(30,30),30,30,Spline);

s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow()+opacity(0.5))); 
s2.colors(palette(s2.map(zpart),Rainbow()+opacity(0.5))); 

draw(s,meshpen=blue);
draw(s2,meshpen=red);

shipout(bbox(2mm,Fill(white)));
```

## Solid surfaces

[image: twosurfsolid]

```
settings.outformat="png";
settings.render=16;

import graph3;
import palette;

size3(150,IgnoreAspect);

currentprojection=orthographic(50,-60,0.4);
//currentlight=(-5,3,20);

real f(pair z){return (1.-0.3)*exp(-z.x*(z.y/100.)*(1.-0.3))-exp(-z.x*(z.y/100.));}
real cero(pair z){return 0.;}

limits((0,0,-0.3),(30,30,0.1));
xaxis3(Label("$x$",1),blue,arrow=Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$y$",1),blue,arrow=Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$z$",1),blue,arrow=Arrow3);

surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(30,30),30,30,Spline);
surface s2=surface(cero,(0,0),(30,30),30,30,Spline);

//s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow+opacity(0.5))); 
//s2.colors(palette(s2.map(zpart),Rainbow()+opacity(0.5))); 

draw(s, blue,meshpen=blue);
draw(s2, red, meshpen=red);

shipout(bbox(2mm,Fill(white)));
```

## PGFplots style (still with Asymptote)

This is the closest I was able to make it look like a `pgfplots` plot.

(Things to do, help is welcomed: 1) automatic point of view (to not depend on the scale of the plot, 2) thick border around each surface 3) vector graphics and hidden surface (e.g. via `bsd` module) 4) details, like small tics and tics spacing)

[image: pngpgfplots2surf]

```
settings.outformat="png";
settings.render=8;
import grid3;
import graph3;
import palette;

size3(160,125,90,IgnoreAspect);
currentprojection=orthographic(30,-60,0.8);

real f(pair z){return (1.-0.3)*exp(-z.x*(z.y/100.)*(1.-0.3))-exp(-z.x*(z.y/100.));}
real cero(pair z){return 0.;}

limits((0,0,-0.3),(30,30,0.1));

xaxis3(Bounds(Min,Min), InTicks());
xaxis3(Bounds(Max,Max));
xaxis3(Bounds(Max,Min));
yaxis3(Bounds(Max,Min), InTicks(beginlabel=false) );
yaxis3(Bounds(Min,Max));
yaxis3(Bounds(Min,Min));
zaxis3(Bounds(Min,Min), InTicks() );
zaxis3(Bounds(Max,Max));
zaxis3(Bounds(Min,Max));

surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(30,30),24,24);
surface s2=surface(cero,(0,0),(30,30),24,24);

draw(s, mean(palette(s.map(zpart),Gradient(blue,yellow,red))),meshpen=0.2pt + black, nolight);
draw(s2, red, meshpen=0.2pt + black, nolight);
draw(s2, red, meshpen=0.2pt + black, nolight);

shipout(bbox(2mm,Fill(white)));
```

---

## Notes

`asymptote` can output vector graphics, but the output is not as good as a raster (rendered) output and removal of hidden faces is very difficult (like with `pgfplots`.)
So, this is big drawback of using asymptote, the plot becomes raster. 
However, it is common that 3D plots quickly become too complex to render with vector graphics.

Comment: Interesting, but I can see the same "zig-zag" issue with patches at the intersection, as in my pgfplots solution. It will be clearer if you choose a fixed different color for each surface.

Comment: As for other external tools, I tried Python matplotlib/mplot3d, but it doesn't do surface intersection at all, which is amazing. Gnuplot does it nicely, but I cannot see how to make it use latex for text without graphics being rasterized. So, for now, I let Matlab win one more battle.

Comment: @iavr, the zig-zag is an issue of transparency (which was not part of the original question). Solid intersections are extremely excellent quality in Asymptote. See my edit. (Of course we are in raster-land, so all is good down to the pixel level).

Comment: Now that's better!!

Answer (score 6):

Yet another hackish solution, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394066/38641). I am adding it here in response to the comment by [alfC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1871/alfc):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10pt}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=10pt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
    plain/.style={every axis plot/.append style={mark=none},enlargelimits=false,grid=none},
    z-sort/.style={z buffer=sort,unbounded coords=jump},
}

\newcommand{\python}[1]{python -c "%
import math, sys; import numpy as np; import scipy.linalg as la;%
#1 np.savetxt(sys.stdout, data)%
"}

\newcommand<>{\pyplot}[3][]%
{\only#4{\addplot[#1] shell[prefix=fig/data/,id=#2,] {\python{#3}};}}

\newcommand<>{\pyplott}[3][]%
{\only#4{\addplot3[z-sort,#1] shell[prefix=fig/data/,id=#2,] {\python{#3}};}}

\newcommand<>{\pyload}[3][]%
{\only#4{\addplot[#1] table[x index=0,y index=#2] {fig/data/#3.out};}}

\newcommand<>{\pyloadt}[2][]%
{\only#3{\addplot3[z-sort,#1] table {fig/data/#2.out};}}

\newcommand{\pysave}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,opacity=0]
    \begin{axis} \pyplot{#1}{#2} \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\pysave{surf}{
    n = 31; x = np.linspace(0,30,n); y = x;
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y);
    Z1 = np.zeros([n, n]);
    Z2 = (1-0.3)*np.exp(-X*(Y/100)*(1-0.3))-np.exp(-X*(Y/100));
    M1 = np.ones([n, n]);
    M2 = 2 * M1;
    N = np.ones([1, n]) * np.NaN;
    X = np.r_[X,  N, X ].reshape([-1, 1]);
    Y = np.r_[Y,  N, Y ].reshape([-1, 1]);
    Z = np.r_[Z1, N, Z2].reshape([-1, 1]);
    M = np.r_[M1, N, M2].reshape([-1, 1]);
    data = np.c_[X, Y, Z, M];
}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    plain,width=\textwidth,height=.8\textwidth,
    colormap={summap}{color=(green);color=(red);color=(yellow);},
]
    \pyloadt[surf,opacity=.7,mesh/cols=31,point meta=\thisrowno{3}]{surf};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: intersection]

So, we only need to provide one expression for each surface, and nothing manual for the intersection(s). And it works for any viewpoint. Such automated solution is needed when surfaces are very complex.

However, the intersection looks ugly because each patch is either drawn or not - while two intersecting patches themselves should be partially visible. I guess a single self-intersecting surface would have the same problem.

Comment: Not that bad. you can cheat and add an intersection line to hide the rough intersection. With lualatex maybe you can have a more sense grid?

Comment: Maybe, but for now I am experimenting with matplotlib PGF backend instead: https://matplotlib.org/users/pgf.html

Comment: If we are going to the external tools realm, many possibilities open up! https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394337/1871