# Intersecting planes not shown correctly with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, matlab

I made a plot in MATLAB of a deformed and an undeformed model. I converted the figure to TikZ using [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz) and added it to my .tex file. I then noticed that the two configurations, which are intersecting, are not displayed correctly. To illustrate what I mean, I've stripped down the TikZ code to make to rectangles cross in a 3D space:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    width=5cm,height=5cm,
    view={-37.5}{45},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-3, xmax=23,
    ymin=0, ymax=20,
    zmin=-5, zmax=5,
    hide axis]
    \addplot3 [fill=white!80!red,opacity=0.5,draw=black] table[row sep=crcr]{
    20 0 0\\
    20 20 0\\
    0 20 0\\
    0 0 0\\
    };

    \addplot3 [fill=white!80!blue,opacity=0.8,draw=black] table[row sep=crcr]{
    15 5 -4\\
    15 15 0\\
    5 15 4\\
    5 5 0\\
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Two crossing planes]

As can be seen one plane lies entirely on top of the other, while in fact they intersect (i.e. about half of the blue plane lies 'underneath' the red plane). 
With my minimum TikZ knowledge I was hoping someone here could help me fix this problem, such that the planes indeed intersect.

Comment: As a workaround may be see [3) Fully Matlab](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108620/15717) section to export figure in a reasonable good quality, you may need to add appropriate packages in `mlf2pdf.m`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem possible in the current version of pgfplots.  From the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) (Section 4.5.1):

> `pgfplots` supports *z* buffering techniques up to a certain extent. It works pretty well for single scatter plots (`z buffer=sort`), mesh or surface plots (`z buffer=auto`) or parametric mesh and surface plots (`z buffer=sort`). *However, it can’t combine different `\addplot` commands, those will be drawn in the order of appearance.* You may encounter the limitations sometimes. Maybe it will be improved in future versions.

Comment: May be Asymptote for it has [better](http://www.piprime.fr/files/asymptote/odoc/colorplanes.png) [3D support](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0010448511001291-gr11.jpg).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Seems like TikZ isn't the way to go for these kind of figures, too bad!

Answer (score 6):

There are several other questions on this issue, for instance:

- [Viviani's curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296499/38641)
- [Plane and cone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52953/38641)
- [Plane and parabola](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/265983/38641)
- [Plane and some more complex surface](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73922/38641)

[As pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109210/38641) by [Matthew Leingang](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1402/matthew-leingang), this is due to a limitation of `pgfplots`.

Unlike all workarounds so far, I have found one (a hack, really) that allows to draw more than one, in fact an arbitrary number of, potentially intersecting, surfaces in a single `addplot3` command, with automatic z buffering, without doing anything manually.

We use `addplot3 table` instead of `addplot3 coordinates`, and we generate data externally. A single surface needs three matrices with `x`, `y`, `z` cordinates. For two surfaces, we can stack together `[x; x]`, `[y; y]` and `[z1; z2]`. To make the two surfaces disconnected, we can insert a vector, say `n`, of `NaN`s of appropriate size between the stacked matrices, e.g. `[x; n; x]`, `[y; n; y]` and `[z1; n; z2]`, together with option `unbounded coords=jump`. Finally, we save the three matrices as three stacked columns representing `(x,y,z)` triplets as `pgfplots` expects. This also requires specifying the number of columns of the matrices with `mesh/cols`.

To implement this idea, I define some macros that allow calling arbitrary `python` code via `addplot shell`, saving the data to a text file in tabular form, and then loading for display. This requires the `-shell-escape` flag in `pdflatex`.

Unfortunately, because this is a single plot, I cannot see how to specify different properties (e.g. color or opacity) for each individual surfaces. Well, maybe by adding a fourth column in the data combined with `point meta` option as in scatter plots, but I haven't tried that.

Also, by trying more complex examples, one realizes that, although patch visibility is computed correctly, we don't really get patch intersection. So, to get the feeling of a smooth curve at the surface intersection, one needs to increase the resolution. I do not intend to use this; I am just sharing because I found it interesting.

Below, I am giving an example of two intersecting planes, but really one could compute anything with the same 'method'. It is in `beamer`, because this is what I was trying already.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10pt}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=10pt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
    plain/.style={every axis plot/.append style={mark=none},enlargelimits=false,grid=none},
    z-sort/.style={z buffer=sort,unbounded coords=jump},
}

\newcommand{\python}[1]{python -c "%
import math, sys; import numpy as np;%
#1 np.savetxt(sys.stdout, data)%
"}

\newcommand<>{\pyplot}[3][]%
{\only#4{\addplot[#1] shell[prefix=fig/data/,id=#2,] {\python{#3}};}}

\newcommand<>{\pyplott}[3][]%
{\only#4{\addplot3[z-sort,#1] shell[prefix=fig/data/,id=#2,] {\python{#3}};}}

\newcommand<>{\pyload}[3][]%
{\only#4{\addplot[#1] table[x index=0,y index=#2] {fig/data/#3.out};}}

\newcommand<>{\pyloadt}[2][]%
{\only#3{\addplot3[z-sort,#1] table {fig/data/#2.out};}}

\newcommand{\pysave}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,opacity=0]
    \begin{axis} \pyplot{#1}{#2} \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\pysave{surf}{
    n = 11; x = np.linspace(0,1,n); y = x;
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y);
    Z1 = X + Y;
    Z2 = 1 - X + Y;
    N = np.ones([1, n]) * np.NaN;
    X = np.r_[X,  N, X ].reshape([-1, 1]);
    Y = np.r_[Y,  N, Y ].reshape([-1, 1]);
    Z = np.r_[Z1, N, Z2].reshape([-1, 1]);
    data = np.c_[X, Y, Z];
}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[plain,width=\textwidth,height=.8\textwidth]
    \pyloadt[surf,mesh/cols=11]{surf};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: intersection of two planes]

**EDIT**

It is possible, eventually, to color each surface differently. I couldn't make `point meta=explicit symbolic` or `point meta=explicit` work, but what did work is `point meta=\thisrowno{3}`. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10pt}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=10pt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
    plain/.style={every axis plot/.append style={mark=none},enlargelimits=false,grid=none},
    z-sort/.style={z buffer=sort,unbounded coords=jump},
}

\newcommand{\python}[1]{python -c "%
import math, sys; import numpy as np;%
#1 np.savetxt(sys.stdout, data)%
"}

\newcommand<>{\pyplot}[3][]%
{\only#4{\addplot[#1] shell[prefix=fig/data/,id=#2,] {\python{#3}};}}

\newcommand<>{\pyplott}[3][]%
{\only#4{\addplot3[z-sort,#1] shell[prefix=fig/data/,id=#2,] {\python{#3}};}}

\newcommand<>{\pyload}[3][]%
{\only#4{\addplot[#1] table[x index=0,y index=#2] {fig/data/#3.out};}}

\newcommand<>{\pyloadt}[2][]%
{\only#3{\addplot3[z-sort,#1] table {fig/data/#2.out};}}

\newcommand{\pysave}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,opacity=0]
    \begin{axis} \pyplot{#1}{#2} \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\pysave{surf}{
    n = 31; x = np.linspace(0,1,n); y = x;
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y);
    Z1 = X + Y;
    Z2 = 1 - X + Y;
    Z3 = 1- X + 1 - Y;
    M1 = np.ones([n, n]);
    M2 = 2 * M1;
    M3 = 3 * M1;
    N = np.ones([1, n]) * np.NaN;
    X = np.r_[X,  N, X,  N, X ].reshape([-1, 1]);
    Y = np.r_[Y,  N, Y,  N, Y ].reshape([-1, 1]);
    Z = np.r_[Z1, N, Z2, N, Z3].reshape([-1, 1]);
    M = np.r_[M1, N, M2, N, M3].reshape([-1, 1]);
    data = np.c_[X, Y, Z, M];
}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    plain,width=\textwidth,height=.8\textwidth,
    colormap={summap}{color=(green);color=(red);color=(yellow);},
]
    \pyloadt[surf,opacity=.7,mesh/cols=31,point meta=\thisrowno{3}]{surf};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In this example I am showing three planes colored in green, red, yellow. A little transparency helps seeing what is going on. It would be very complex in this case to compute intersections manually with `min` and `max` as in previous workarounds.

However, the missing patch intersections are now evident between the green and yellow planes, so I increased the resolution to 31x31. Further increasing to 41x41 gives `TeX capacity exceeded`, which is very sad. Anyhow, here is the result:

[image: intersection of three colored planes]

Comment: Try using lualatex to avoid the capacity limits.