# 3D figure using tikz-pgf - Intersection of two planes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a figure using tikz-pgf. This figure should have two planes in it: z=x and z=0. So far I've managed to write the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1,y domain=-1:1]
        \addplot3[surf] {0};
        \addplot3[surf] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

But the result is weird, because it's not clear where the intersection of both planes is. I would like the plane z=0 to "cover" a bit of the plane z=x, as if the figure was viewed from above. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks for the suggestion, I just edited the code.

Comment: Maybe related and helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73922/124842 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52954/124842

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thank you, I'll have a look but I doubt I can manage to solve it, it's the first time I try to draw a plot in Latex and that code seems complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the method of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73962/124842). There a combination of surface colors, opacities and plots get close to the desired result.

Your intersection is `x=0`, `y=-1:1`, `z=0` with `\addplot3+` you can draw this line. `mark=none` disables the marks. Optional you can use the style `thick`.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1,y domain=-1:1]
        \addplot3[surf, opacity=0.35] {0};
        \addplot3[surf, opacity=0.35] {x};
        \addplot3+[mark=none,thick]({0},{y},{0});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```